What is the name of this aircraft?
The photo was taken in Daegu, South Korea and is not visible on Flightradar24. I could hear the sound of turboprop engines.

(full image)

My first thought was King Air C90 but the image quality is too poor to be sure.

I'd guess Piper Seneca. I know it's not a turboprop but that looks like it.

Perhaps it's a CASA/IPTN CN-235? It meets the turbo-prop criteria, and the wing looks similar. South Korea operates the type

The Seneca has a constant chord wing where this aircraft has a taper. The CN-235 is a high-wing design while this aircraft is clearly low wing.

I too think it might be an early King Air 90. Or maybe an RC aircraft. https://hobbyking.com/en_us/avios-pnf-kingtwin-1700-sports-scale-executive-turboprop-airplane-1700mm.html

Do you have any other images or perhaps a video link we could use to help identify the aircraft?
